# Как правильно передавать параметры в запрос

Tags: delphi, datetime, firebird, datetimepicker

В бд(Firebird 3) данные хранятся как timestamp. Надо вытащить записи по интервалу времени **в коротком формате**,например, продажи с 1.08.2020 по 2.08.2020.
Компонент datetimepicker :

SQL:

```
select sum(Summa),users.user_name
from  table1,users
where (table1dt between :date1 and :date2) and
      (table1.user_id=users.user_id) 
group by users.user_name
```

Delphi:

```
Form1.Quser.Close;
Form1.qUser.ParamByName('date1').AsDate:=Form1.DateTimePicker1.Date;       
Form1.qUser.ParamByName('date2').AsDate:=Form1.DateTimePicker2.Date;       
Form1.qUser.open;
```

Как выдно на скриншоте значение комонента DateTimePicker1 в short формате(01.08.2020),а в  параметре передаётся почему-то  **в длинном формате**(01.08.2020 16:49:47), хотя в object inspector параметры :date, :date2 имеют тип данных **date** а не datetime.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в бд Firebird:

[image: в бд]

Comment: `DateOf(DateTimePicker1.Date)`. `TDate` & `TDateTime` & `TTime` - синонимы и де-факто являются типом `Double`

Comment: Это не длинный/короткий форматы, а дата со временем и дата без времени. слово формат уместно только когда речь идет о преобразовании между датой и строкой

Answer (score 2):

`TDate` / `TDateTime` / `TTime` - синонимы, и, по факту, являются типом `Double` (в целой части лежат дни, в дробной - доля дня).

Если вам нужно передавать дату, то приводите к ней вот так - `DateOf(DateTimePicker1.Date)`.